# How can jelastic mount /?

Tags: jelastic

When I create python buy dashboard and go to CLI in jeastic and run lsblk
I can see that the / is mount. is python container or CentOS?
If it is container how can they mount /?because in kubernetes we can not mount /?
If it is CentOS why I do not have full permission?!

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: in kuberentes I can not mout the root. but in jelastic i can see that the / is mount to 400 Gb SSD. it means it is a VM that can mount /. because in container we could not assign / a volume to persist its information.

Answer (score 2):

Jelastic is full on containers, no VMs are used there for now. In container it is possible to mount / if you have enough privileges for that, that works for both Kubernetes and Jelastic. Python image is also working inside container, by default you are connecting to SSH over jelastic user that has limited permissions that is why you cannot mount /.  If you contact your hosting service provider I believe they will be able to provide you root access.

Comment: How can I mount / in kubernetes?what privileges  it needs?

Comment: I get this error?
 invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid specification: destination can't be '/'